# Using PHPUnit on a Zend Framework application, how can I force the locale to be used for a given test?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, zend-locale

I am testing a multi-lingual site with phpunit.  One of the tests I want to perform is that the application will detect the locale of the user and automatically redirect.

That is, user accesses the site on /.   The application detects they're from France and redirects to /fr-FR/

The application does appear to do this, but trying to write a unit test for this seems impossible.  I need to forge the locale for the purpose of the test.  Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 4):

The solution has been to make the code itself more testable.

In my test I have:

```
    $locale = new Zend_Locale();

    $locale->setLocale('fr_FR');
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);
```

And now in my app I use:

```
    $locale = Zend_Locale::findLocale(); 
    $locale = new Zend_Locale($locale);
```

To set the locale.  As findLocale checks the Zend_Registry for an entry first.

Comment: No need to use two lines when one will do: `$locale = new Zend_Locale(Zend_Locale::findLocale());`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably looking at the [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) header that the browser sends. You can access this in PHP using `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`. It's a global, so in your test setup, you could change its value:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = "en";
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work.  This isn't set by default as it's running from the command line and even when I set it as above or using putenv this still doesn't work.

I am using Zend_Locale within my app to perform the detection.

Comment: I have tried:

        $locale = new Zend_Locale();
        $locale->setDefault('fr_FR');
        $locale->setLocale('fr_FR');
        Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale); 
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
  $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = 'fr_FR';
        putenv("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=fr_FR");